# What's the first appearance of Becoming the Costume that happens on Halloween?

Tags: first-appearance, trope

What's the first appearance of [Becoming the Costume](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BecomingTheCostume) that happens on Halloween?

> Something turns people into whatever costume they are wearing.

Comment: What do you mean by Halloween? The holiday or the film?

Comment: @Catija - I mean the day. If I meant the movie, I'd have said, "in Halloween" instead. ... Should I rephrase into Halloween Day or something?

Comment: The tag is for the film, not the day. We don't have tags for holidays. Everything else is fine :D

Comment: @Catija - Ah. ... I didn't know, 'cause the tag had no description? But that does make sense.

Comment: Yeah, I just submitted one, so hopefully it will get approved so people can see :D We get so many film tags, sometimes we don't get a chance to create tag wiki excerpts but it's fixed-ish now. :D

Comment: I'm still kind of confused by the trope's definition. Could you maybe give a couple examples?

Comment: @sanpaco - What's confusing about the definition? ... I guess I could require that the costume be Halloween Costume, but nah?

Comment: I can't think of a single example of someone becoming their Halloween costume in a movie or TV show. The tropes link doesn't provide any examples. So I'm wondering if you have an example or two so it's clear what would fit the description?

Comment: @sanpaco - Live Action TV: Buffy The Vampire Slayer.

Comment: @Malandy how does that fit the description? Sorry I'm not trying to be difficult. Was buffy wearing a costume that made her become a vampire slayer?

Comment: @sanpaco - Sorry, yeah... Okay, so... [Halloween](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Recap/BuffyTheVampireSlayerS2E6Halloween): Ethan, a shop owner, sells Halloween Costumes to people, then casts a spell so the people wearing his costumes become what the costumes depict.

Answer (score 5):

Great and interesting question!

From the looks of it, the first instance of [Becoming the Costume](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BecomingTheCostume) is

> The Twilight Zone (1959) has "The Masks", where a dying millionaire forces his worthless heirs to wear masks caricaturing their worst personality traits - if they take them off before midnight, they get cut out of his will save for some fare to take the train home. At midnight, he dies, and they shed the masks... and discover their faces have taken on the shapes of the masks permanently save the good-hearted millionaire. He retains his human face. It should be noted this isn't set on Halloween, but Mardi Gras in New Orleans.

Although not set in Halloween as requested, it may have inspired other occurrences like:

> The House That Dripped Blood: In "The Cloak", actor Henderson purchases a vampire's cloak to add verisimilitude to role as a vampire, only to discover he transforms into a vampire whenever he dons the cloak.

The House That Dripped Blood is a 1971 British horror Anthology Film directed by Peter Duffell and distributed by Amicus Productions

and

> The TV special Witch's Night Out (1978) has a witch turn two kids and their babysitter into the monsters they're costumed as. When the adults find out and turn on her, she explains that the point of Halloween is to try out different personas and imagine your potential. The adults happily start calling out requests for one-night transformations themselves.